# Is it possible to use aws sts to generate a token so I can use aws cli in another machine?

Tags: aws-cli

It is the use case: My aws account is using aws identity with MFA enabled. I have some long running jobs I wish to be able to run on an ec2 instance.

Is it possible to generate some kind of token using `aws sts` such that I can use in the ec2 instance to grant my job scripts access to some aws resources?

Answer (score 1):

EC2 instances already fetch short-term credentials from STS periodically. 
You just need to create an IAM role, and assign this role to your instance as an [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-instance-profile).